# Getting NaN in R in bootstrap

Tags: r, nan, statistics-bootstrap

I have the following function in R that I will bootstrap:

```
robustri <- function(xv,gam=0.95,indices) {
            d <- xv[indices] # allows boot to select sample
            pc <- (1+gam)/2
            cc <- 1/(0.581734 - 0.607227*gam)
            x <- sort(d)
            nx <- length(x)
            tpctpt <- qt(pc,(nx-1))
            ...
 }
```

When I run the bootstrap:

```
 boot(data=dataex , statistic=robustri , R=5)
```

I get these warnings:

> In qt(pc, (nx - 1)) : NaNs produced

However, when I bypass the required bootstrap syntax (the indices parameter)
and just run on my data everything is fine.

Comment: It's `function(xv, indices, gam = 0.95)`. The `indices` must be the second argument.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "rolling your own" bootstrap like this:

```
#specify number of bootstrap samples
B <- 1000

#create storage vector to hold output from each bootstrap sample
resultvec <- numeric(B)

#get length of data so we don't have to recompute this in each iteration
N <- nrow(mydata)

#do bootstrap
for(b in seq(B)) {
    #take a sample of your data
    this_boot_sample <- mydata[sample(1:N, size=N, replace=T), ]
    #calculate your statistic of interest and save it
    resultvec[b] <- myfun(this_boot_sample)
}
```

Then when you hit the error, you should be able to dive in and diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful.